# Appending IV onto encrypted file for later decryption

Tags: java, encryption, file-io, initialization-vector

I am trying to append a 16 byte securely generated IV onto each file after it is encrypted but before it is written. This is so  that I can decrypt it later by pulling the IV off the file. This is my code so far:

```
public static void encrypt(byte[] file, String password, String fileName, String dir)
        throws Exception {
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
    //128 bit IV generated for each file
    byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
    r.nextBytes(iv);

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), "AES");

    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivspec);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir + fileName);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

    // Have to append IV --------


    cos.write(file);

    fos.flush();
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    fos.close();
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir + fileName);
fos.write(iv);

CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
```

should do the trick. The IV can be written to the file before the Cipher is even set up.

Comment: I don't have much experience with this but wouldn't the IV get encrypted with the file if it is done this way? If so then how would I use the Encrypted IV to decrypt the file?

Comment: The CipherOutputStream works on top of the FileOutputStream and both are sequential. If you write something to the FileOutputStream and then attach a CipherOutputStream, it has no idea what was written. The reverse works in the same way. So, you instantiate a FileInputStream, read 16 bytes from that and then create a Cipher object from the key and IV and then attach a CipherInputStream to the FileInputStream.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Greatly appreciated!